# Automapper.mapper.map doesn't work but mapper.dynamicmap work

Tags: c#, automapper

First of all, sorry for my bad english! I'm french.

I tried to find on google but without any result so, this is my automapper configuration :

```
public void CreateMap(IMapperConfiguration cfg)
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<GroupeApplication, GroupeApplicationContract>();
        cfg.CreateMap<Application, ApplicationContract>()
            .ForMember(d => d.GroupeApplicationId, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.GroupeApplication != null ? s.GroupeApplication.Id : Guid.Empty));

        cfg.CreateMap<Application, ApplicationWithAscendantContract>()
            .ForMember(d => d.GroupeApplication, o => o.MapFrom(s => Mapper.Map<GroupeApplicationContract>(s.GroupeApplication)));
        cfg.CreateMap<GroupeApplication, GroupeApplicationWithDescendantContract>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Applications, o => o.MapFrom(s => Mapper.Map<List<ApplicationContract>>(s.Applications)));

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
```

In fact, groupeapplication has list of application, and Mapper.Map failed when it try to map my applications collection... this is the error message :

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types:
>   Application -> ApplicationContract
>   UGO.Distribution.Domain.Application -> UGO.Distribution.Shared.Contracts.ApplicationContract
>
> Destination path:
>   List`1[0]
>
> Source value:
>   UGO.Distribution.Domain.Application

If I replace the last config with this it works (I replace Mapper.Map by Mapper.DynamicMap) :

```
cfg.CreateMap<GroupeApplication, GroupeApplicationWithDescendantContract>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Applications, o => o.MapFrom(s => Mapper.DynamicMap<List<ApplicationContract>>(s.Applications)));
```

I could be satisfied, but that is not for me is that this method is deprecated in automapper 4.0.3 !!

Is there any explanation or a better solution for this problem?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `Group` instead of `Groupe`?

Comment: @NickBull he said that at start of question "I am french" :) :)

Comment: @HakamFostok no no, I'm not knocking that! I mean is the class actually named `Group` instead of `Groupe`, causing a Type error.

Comment: What version of AutoMapper?

Comment: it's GroupeApplication and not Group... like Hakam Fostok said, I'm French ;) I use automapper 4.2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting `ForMember(...)`, try:

```
ForMember<ObjectThatYouWantMap>(...);
```